# Trait not implemented for (thing that implements trait)

Tags: rust, traits

So, Rust is trying to tell me a fib, I think, but maybe I'm just out of my mind...

```
fn get_random<T, R>(range: Range<T>, rng: &mut R) -> T
    where T: SampleRange + PartialOrd,
          R: Rng
{
    range.ind_sample(&mut rng)
}
```

The where clause there should indicate that R *definitely* implements Rng, otherwise... Well, come on, right? But when I try to compile this, it swears up and down that rng does not implement rand::Rng.

What on earth?

> rustc 1.0.0-nightly (cfea8ec41 2015-03-10) (built 2015-03-11) (in case you were wondering)

Comment: Please post enough code so that we can copy and paste it and it compiles with the same error. This is called [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it helps us answer your question quicker, and it might even help you understand it more. Also include the *exact* error, not "*it swears up and down*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the actual error generated:

```
<anon>:10:11: 10:31 error: the trait `rand::Rng` is not implemented for the type `&mut R` [E0277]
<anon>:10     range.ind_sample(&mut rng)
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'll highlight **for the type &mut R**. Your issue stems from the fact that you are taking too many references. Your `rng` is a `&mut R`. You are *then* trying to take another reference to it when calling `ind_sample`. This would create a `&mut &mut R`, which doesn't implement `Rng`.

```
use std::rand::distributions::range::SampleRange;
use std::rand::Rng;
use std::rand::distributions::Range;
use std::rand::distributions::IndependentSample;

 fn get_random<T, R>(range: Range<T>, rng: &mut R) -> T
    where T: SampleRange + PartialOrd,
          R: Rng
{
    range.ind_sample(rng)
}

fn main() {}
```